# How to automate pie charts and bar graphs using selenium?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, kendo-ui, webdriver

I just want to automate the chart action in Selenium? Web-driver/Java 
(Kendo Ui)

how can i click on the chart segments??

My graph is exactly same link in the below link

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/pie-charts/index

Answer (score 2):

ya i got the solution.... this is the code to drill down in chart

```
WebElement svg = gd.findElement(By.cssSelector("svg"));
List<WebElement> outertext = svg.findElements(By.cssSelector("text"));

                for(WebElement texts : outertext)
                    {
                        String textcollection = texts.getText();
                        if(textcollection.equals("xxxxxx"))
                            {
                                texts.click();
                            }
                    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Finding xpath of the elements inside the svg tag is bit different than finding xpath of other elements.

Suppose your URL is:

**https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart**

If you have to find the text of the element in the pie-chart then you can use the code mentioned below:

**driver.findElement(By.xpath(" //*[@id='piechart']/div/div[1]/div/*[name()='svg']/*[name()='g'][4]/*[name()='text']")).getText();**

Answer (score 1):

I have to automate a lot of pages that heavily use different controls of Kendo. I'm working at Telerik, and we are using Test Studio for our automation. However, you can apply our approach. 
I usually read the javascript API documentation for the control that I want to automate. There are tons of methods that can be executed for every one of them.

Example: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/kendo
You just need to find the appropriate method for your case and execute it the javascript via Web driver:

```
WebDriver driver = new AnyDriverYouWant();
if (driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor) {
    ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("yourScript();");
}
```

You can create extensions methods around the controls for these particular methods.

If you have questions, don't hesitate to contact me!

Comment: thanks for the reply Anton..here I wanna drill down in the graph to the end to the end....but here i cant find class,but i can find id,but it is dynamic..how can i identify the element in this???...

Comment: If I were you, I was going to create predefined demos for my tests. Actually the QAs from Kendo controls, do exactly this. When you have predefined demo, you can use the "d" attribute values to locate your elements. "d="M0 0 L 1275 0 1275 400 0 400Z" :)

Comment: how can i use the attribute "d"..can u please explain with syntax.....Anton my D value is                  "d="M 547.008 83.841 A119 119 0 0,1 623.5 56 L 623.5 175 z""

Comment: this is a brilliant answer!

Comment: First open Chrome Developer tools or firebug. Then locate your element- <path d="M0 0 L 1275 0 1275 400 0 400Z" stroke="none" fill="#fff"></path>  In order to locate this element you can use xpath locator- driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@d='M0 0 L 1275 0 1275 400 0 400Z']"))       I hope that helps you. :)

Comment: Anton am getting this error when i executed the script                 org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (409, 164). Other element would receive the click: <text id="k10007" data-model-id="k10020" x="329" y="41" fill-opacity="1" style="font: 11px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; " fill="#000">...</text>

Comment: <g><path id="k10019" style="display: block;" data-model-id="k10007" d="M 547.008 83.841 A119 119 0 0,1 623.5 56 L 623.5 175 z" stroke-width="0.5" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-linejoin="round" fill-opacity="1" stroke-opacity="1" fill="#5fbbad"></path><path id="k10006" style="display: block;" data-model-id="k10007" d="M 547.008 83.841 A119 119 0 0,1 623.5 56 L 623.5 175 z" stroke-width="0.5" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-linejoin="round" fill-opacity="1" stroke-opacity="1" fill="url(#k10018)"></path></g>

Comment: @AntonAngelov i have added my g tag elements for your reference.... This is my script--                    WebElement chart =  gd.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@d='M 547.008 83.841 A119 119 0 0,1 623.5 56 L 623.5 175 z']"));
chart.click();

Comment: Yeah, you cannot use web driver directly. You can execute the following JavaScript- var el= $("[d='M35.5 75.5 L 545.5 75.5 545.5 88.5 35.5 88.5Z']"); el.click(); If you try this code in the console and type el. -> all available methods of the control will be displayed.

Comment: can you please elaborate this...sorry am new to webdriver and javascript @AntonAngelov...;(

Comment: Sure no problem. Can you please provide me some sort of test URL or similar page and explain to me exactly what are you trying to automate. Because I'm not completely sure that I understand the need to click on bar s. :)

Comment: @AntonAngelov this is the url which is similar to my chart > http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/pie-charts/index...the same chart is used in my site..here we can't click on the chart..you just show the way how to locate the elements in the chart then i'll try to do it...

Comment: Please refer to the following image: [Example](http://screencast.com/t/VzrlV3txwwh). I hope that helps you! Please, if my answer helped you, mark them as answered and upvote them. Thank you in advance! Anton

Comment: WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("var el = $("[d='M717.733 298.286 L 730.122 327.8 747.302 327.8']"); el.click();");
This should do the trick.